# Unable to append HTML to a list using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following CSS that forms a directory tree. I want to be able to dynamically append `<li>` tags with `N` number of children `<ul>` tags to the existing `dirTree`. No matter what I try, I just end up appending raw text or the styles aren't being applied correctly.

I'm not a CSS guy, but I was inspecting in dev tools and see `:before` and `:after`, but not quite sure how to attach this using jquery.

The below code should be able to run in a static file without issues.
Thanks.

```js
$("#dirTree").append("<li>Parent Directory</li><ul>child1</ul><ul>child2</ul>");
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-family: monospace;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
}
ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 10px;
}
ul li:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -7px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100%;
}
ul li.root {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -20px;
}
ul li.root:before {
  display: none;
}
ul li.root:after {
  display: none;
}
ul li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="directoryPanel">
  <div class="dir">
    <ul id="dirTree">
      <li class="root">
        File Explorer
      </li>
      <li>
        Want to create a new directory? Click here
        <ul>
          <li>Click here to upload a file</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the jQuery code you mentioned?

Comment: _"not quite sure how to attach this using jquery"_ <- You don't need to generate the pseudo `:before` and `:after` elements; they are created by the CSS.

Comment: Adding the code now. That is effectively what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Looks ok (I guess) here ~ http://jsfiddle.net/bfsaw1rz/. Can you elaborate on the problem? Only odd thing I can see is text in your `<ul>` elements (ie `<ul>child1</ul>`) which you wouldn't typically have

Comment: In chrome it is just rendering as raw text when I add via dev tools, is that normal? Also seems like the branching style got removed in your example for the children

Comment: Should be `$("#dirTree").append("<li>Parent Directory</li><ul><li>child1</li></ul><ul><li>child2</li></ul>");` -- Notice the `<li>` wrapping child1 and child2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"add via dev tools"_? Your question is very unclear

Comment: @Phil I opened up dev tools and ran the jquery code in the console to see it take effect in a little sandbox.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Ooo seems to be working in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*«...seems like the branching style got removed...»*

You are missing the `<li>` in your markup. The "branching style" is tied to it.

Moreover, some text within a `<ul>` but without `<li>` is invalid markup.

```js
$("#dirTree").append("<li>Parent Directory</li><ul><li>child1</li></ul><ul><li>child2</li></ul>");
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-family: monospace;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
}
ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 10px;
}
ul li:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -7px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100%;
}
ul li.root {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -20px;
}
ul li.root:before {
  display: none;
}
ul li.root:after {
  display: none;
}
ul li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="directoryPanel">
  <div class="dir">
    <ul id="dirTree">
      <li class="root">
        File Explorer
      </li>
      <li>
        Want to create a new directory? Click here
        <ul>
          <li>Click here to upload a file</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul>li` structure seems entirely wrong in your jQuery. You have written css for `li` tags and appending `ul` tags as childs. That's where it caused the problem. In my answer I added a `ul` and inside the `ul` I have multiple `li` as your dynamic children.

For a clear definition **I broke your jQuery into multiple lines** which will be easier to read and understand

```js
$("#dirTree").append("<li>Parent Directory</li>");
$("#dirTree").append("<ul id='parent'></ul>");
$("#parent").append("<li>child1</li>");
$("#parent").append("<li>child2</li>");
$("#parent").append("<li>child3</li>");
$("#parent").append("<li>child4</li>");
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 10px;
}

ul li:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  bottom: -7px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li.root {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -20px;
}

ul li.root:before {
  display: none;
}

ul li.root:after {
  display: none;
}

ul li:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="directoryPanel">
  <div class="dir">
    <ul id="dirTree">
      <li class="root">
        File Explorer
      </li>
      <li>
        Want to create a new directory? Click here
        <ul>
          <li>Click here to upload a file</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```